# Collecting same words in an array, C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

If I had an array that looks like :
'A\t2\nB\t5\nC\t6\nB\t2\n' <- alphabet and numbers are separated by a tab(\t) and a new line(\n) after the number.

I need to collect the same alphabet together also summing the number behind of alphabet. If printing out the output should looks like:
'A\t2\nB\t7\nC\t6'.

I thought of using a strcmp function, but the input array may change so I wont be able to know what alphabet is in it.

edit: sorry, I think my question is not clear. My array is not only a character, but it can be a sequence of character+numbers too. such as: 'THIS\t25\nTHESE\t67\nTHOSE\t2\nTHESE\t102\nTHOSE23\t55\n'

Comment: streamline the input buffer array, parse it to feed a state machine (for tab and newline separations) which update a map letter->number and ouput the alphabet when hitting '\0'

Comment: My knowledge of C is very limited, I tried to separate them into a 2D arrays so that I can try comparing them that way, but, im stuck from there. So I saw a strcmp function, but it need another array as a reference in order to compare.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the current line's alphabet into `char c` and the number into `int i` and have a `int alpha[26]` defined with all entries initialised to `0`.  Then you just have to:

```
alpha[c - 'A'] += i;
```

then just print out all non-zero entries in `alpha`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if when the alphabet(A or B...) had become a sequence of alphabet(ACC or BAC...), I wont be able to do in this way.

Comment: @user2793574 in that case you have c1, c2, and c3 and one way to deal with that is `alpha[(c1 - 'A')*26*26 + (c2 - 'A')*26 + c3 - 'A'] += i`

Comment: @Paul then you have a 17576-element array for what is probably not going to be anywhere near 17576 unique strings. And what about 4 characters? 5? I think this calls for a hash map.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect each character at a time and use a switch to produce the desire output...
like...

```
getch(c);
switch(c)
{
  //case for alphabets

  //case for numbers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first find smallest letter (by ASCII code number ex. A=65), search input strings for this letter (maybe using strchr) and summ (in separate variable) all numbers relative to this letter, at the end, write letter and number in new string and proceed with next letter (B=66).
Then you'll have new string sorted and summarized.

```
char *input;
char *output;
char *p, *cur;
int nums, num;
char min;
char temp[20];
//search for minimal letter
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
    if(input[i] > 65 && input[i] < 90)
        if(input[i] < min)
            min = input[i];
}
//parsing input string
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input)/4; i++){
//strlen(input)/4 because each sequense at least 4 letters
    p = input;
    num = 0;
    nums = 0;
    while(cur = strchr(p, min)){
        sscanf(cur+2, "%d", &num);
        nums += num;
        p = cur+1;
    }
    //filling new string
    sprintf(temp, "%c\t%d\n", min, nums);
    strcat(output, temp);
    min++;
}
```

Comment: how is it when the alphabet is a longer words? sorry, my question is not clear, i re-edited my main post.

Comment: Sorting will be complex, but it can be solved as separate task.
As for gathering, first, you can take first word, strcpy() it, replace it with spaces, and compare with every word after '\n' in string (p=strchr(input, "\n"); if(!strcmp(p+1, saved_word))). Then replace with spaces every occurence of your word in string. Then take next word in string and repeat procedure. It will be slower, but solves your task. Also pay attention at storing words, you'll have to allocate enough memory for alphabet, but it's not hard.